# Connecting to a private Blockchain via a Dapp

Tags: ether, dapps, private-blockchain

How can I choose an a node to randomly connect to on the cluster?

I can already connect my Dapp to the private node. But what happens in case that node is not available or a different node is more closer to the Dapp user?

Basically a node provider for a private blockchain.